# Python DiGraph - Dynamic Source Data

Tags: python, networkx, orgchart, digraphs

This is probably a moon shot, but I'm looking to get started with my first Python project and I'm looking for advice.

The goal is to write some code that would be able to create the following graph.  The issue is that I would need the code to be dynamic in that it could read source data (Parent/Child relations).

The output would look something like this
[Organizational Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz7OL.png).

I've started looking into networkx MultiDiGraph, but there's a lot to learn.

EDIT *Would this count as a loop with regards to MultiDiGraph, or would it be just a node to node loop? (direct vs indirect loop)*
[Organizational Chart Indirect Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DGh0.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you just want to represent a DiGraph, or do you actually need to produce output?  Printed or screen?  Networkx is probably your best shot.  I'm not sure why you're looking at MultiDiGraph -- I don't see any loops.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tim.  I added an edit for MultiDiGraph, I'm not sure if a loop is only node to node or any indirect loop counts  (there are 2 loops, E-C-B and E-D-B).

As for what I'm looking for, I want to be able to produce printable/on screen content.

Comment: DiGraph can handle loops.  MultiDiGraph, as I understand it, is for graphs where some sections are disconnected.  Networkx can do printing through matplotlib.  I really think it is the right choice for you.